# how to execute join query in realm with swift?

Tags: swift, realm

I want to execute join query

```
table1)
class student 
{
   name:String
   classcode:Int
}

table2)
class classcode
{
   classcode:Int
   name:String
}
```

Data example

```
student:

| name | classcode |
| john | 001       |
| Kim  | 002       |

classcode:

| classcode | name     |
| 001       | computer | 
| 002       | Math     |
```

I want to get output -? `john,computer`

How can I execute the query in Realm?

Comment: I think you should present some effort and describe what you're having trouble with

Comment: I believe you're thinking in a SQL-way. It's not bad, though. Anyway, Realm allows 1-to-1 and 1-to-many relationships. Check it out: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#to-one-relationships I suggest you to create a `classcode` property in the `student` class. Then the info will be accessible as simple as `myStudent.class.name`

Comment: @Orlando : thank you !!   class student{ name:String , class:classcode}    right?   realm is no join database?   only inserting object can all data between 2 table?

Comment: @ttoggaiman I don't know exactly if Realm is not a join db, I've never tried doing so because the relationships it provides are just for this scenarios. The object defined as you wrote it will work. The `student` class object will be linked with the `classcode` instance you assign.

Comment: @Oralando : thanks your reply i have a question,   if i have a low data  ex) student.csv and classcode.csv   just imported csv using realm browser  that made 2 object  but that no have relationships..    in this case ... how can i make a relationships or .. how can i get correct data   ..  if i use mssql or mysql  select * from student a ,classcode b and a.classcode=b.classcode    result->    john 001  001 computer     in realm how can i query from realm made by csvfile

Comment: @ttoggaiman did you ever figure out how to create relationships from csv import?

Answer (score 2):

Realm is an object-based database, so the concept of joins in queries doesn't apply to it.

In this particular case, it would be appropriate to set up `classcode` objects as a list in the `student` class. Like so:

```
class Class: Object {
   dynamic var classCode = 0
   dynamic var name = ""
}

class Student: Object {
   dynamic var name = ""
   let classes = List<Class>()
}

--- 

let realm = try! Realm()

let computerClass = Class()
computerClass.classCode = 1
computerClass.name = "Computer"

let newStudent = Student()
newStudent.name = "John"
newStudent.classes.append(computerClass)

try! realm.write {
    realm.add(computerClass)
    realm.add(newStudent)
}
```

Realm `List` objects do not store copies of `Object` instances; they only store references to the corresponding `Object` in its table. In this way, it replicates the same sort of setup you'd expect in a join query.

Let me know if you need anymore clarification! :)

Comment: I have a question ..if Student has 100 rows and each of student has  computerclass ..  then computerclass made 100 object? or computerclass made distinct of all object?

Comment: It depends which `Class` object each `Student` is pointing to. If only 1 `Class` object exists, and every single one of those 100 `Student` objects point at it, then you could easily have 100 `Student` objects, and only 1 `Class` object. :)